# Create a new photoshop cs6 shortcut

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I want to set the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> to use as my "flip horizontal", and it works fine until I restart. Then photoshop replaces it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>&</kbd> and I have to re-set the shortcut everytime.

Any clue how to make the keyboard shortcut stay as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> permanently?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your file system is wrong or something, it should get stored.

Anyway try saving a new Set, and using it as default, maybe CS6's default keyboard shortcut set is getting overwritted on each boot.